# Parse error when programmatically installing an APK from Assets Folder

Tags: java, android, package, apk

I am trying to install apk programatically from assets folder,  But Parse Error
I have Googled for days and fine almost everything is fine but still error exists
Here is my code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application>
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

</application
```

file_provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />

    <root-path name="root" path="." />

</paths>
```

MainActivity

```
private void installApk() {

        File f = new File("file:///android_asset/app.apk");
        f.setReadable(true, false);
        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",f);


        Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        installIntent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(installIntent);

}
```

Checking Permission

```
    private void checkWriteExternalStoragePermission() {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))));
            }
        }


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            installApk();
        } else {
            installApk();
        }
    }

    private void requestWriteExternalStoragePermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,  new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode==MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           
                installApk();
           

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Not Granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

File app.apk location : main->assets

Please Note even I write file as

`File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "app.apk");`

and still parse error

TargetSDK = 31

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install APK directly from assets folder because that folder is not accessible to system's package installer. You must first copy that APK to a shared folder like public documents directory and then pass the URI of file from that directory to intent

```
val publicDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
```

Edit: Steps to copy file to external storage:

```
val file = new File("file:///android_asset/app.apk");
val publicDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
val destinationAPKFile = File(publicDir, "your_apk_name.apk")
try {
      FileUtils.copyFile(file, destinationAPKFile)
     } 
catch (e: Exception) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can use the URI of destinationAPKFile and install APK as you are doing.

Edit 2: In java

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/app.apk");
File publicDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
File destinationAPKFile = File(publicDir, "your_apk_name.apk");
try {
      FileUtils.copyFile(file, destinationAPKFile)
     } 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit 3:
To use FileUtils.copyTo, add following dependency to your app level gradle

```
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

Comment: How to copy it  , could you please write it

Comment: Thanks sir but this is kotlin , could you write in java

Comment: but       FileUtils.copyFile(file, destinationAPKFile)
the cannot resolve metho copyfile

Comment: could you please fix and mark your answer as correct one

Comment: add this to your app level gradle implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

Comment: still problem exists copyFile cannot resolve method

Comment: make sure you have imported the correct FileUtils: import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Comment: 'android.os.FileUtils' is already defined in a single-type import.

Comment: Thanks but still problem exists

Comment: HI sir problem fixed but java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'file:/android_asset/app.apk' does not exist

Comment: your file address should be file:///android_asset/app.apk not file:/android_asset/app.apk  you are missing some '/'. If you are still facing the issue, you can try placing the apk in res/raw folder and access by using InputStream ins  = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(
                "app",
                "raw", packageName
            )
        )

Comment: : java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@86b788' does not exist

Comment: what is the name of your APK you kept in the asset folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245639/discussion-between-kim-jong-yung-and-mohit48).